# How to get the value of an inner Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Here is my dictionary.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

I need to get the value of the `int` in the inner dictionary.

```
foreach (var country in dic)
{
    output.AppendFormat("{0} (total population: {1})", country.Key, HERE);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: `country.Value` is, itself, a `Dictionary<string, int>` at `country.Key` in `dic`. There are potentially *many* `int` values in *each* of the inner dictionaries. It's not clear what, exactly, your aim is here.

Comment: I need to get the the value of the inner dictionary which is int, in this case.

Comment: @jdweng are you sure about it? maybe `dic["abc"]["xyz"]`?

Comment: Had brackets in wrong place.

Comment: You need *another* key to get to an int value in the nested dictionary. The value you have *isn't* an int in your example, it's a collection of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a population sum (*"total popuplation"*), you can use:

```
   var sum = country.Value.Values.Sum();
   output.AppendFormat("{0} (total population: {1})", country.Key, sum);
```

This uses LINQ, so you are required to have

```
using System.Linq;
```

in your source file.

Comment: Thanks. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this sample in degugger:

```
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
        var cities = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        cities.Add("Kiev", 6000000);
        cities.Add("Lviv", 4000000);

        dic.Add("Ukraine", cities);

        var totalPopulationByCountry = dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Values);
        var sumPopulationByCountry = dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Values.Sum());
```

should be what you need